# Selenium Java - How to verify that a browser notification is displayed?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I am using Java and Selenium in order to test a web application that requires Adobe Flash Player to be enabled in order to continue.  I am trying to verify that a browser's notification displays (See below image).  I am not looking to click/select "allow" or "block", I am only testing to see if the notification displays in the browser.  How could I accomplish this?  I would be testing a variety of different browsers including chrome, firefox, internet explorer, microsoft edge, and safari.

[Browser notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCjP.png)

Comment: You can check for the presence of the [Alert](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html).

Comment: @Brian, this is not an alert. I've just tried - NoAlertPresentException.